# How do I change the default validation error of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute`

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a class like below (simplified) and I like to replace the default validation error with my own messages. I know I can set the message directly when I am adding the attribute, but it is too much pain and it is error prune to add the same message 10,000 time in the same code.

```
Public class CreateUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A specific message")]//Don't like to do this
    [MinLength(10)]// Like to write specific text 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have looked into their code and apparently they are using [ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netcore-3.1) to set the actual message from the key. The documentation just describes the way to handle windows applications. How do I add the resources in Asp.net core application and overwrite the default values?

### Update

From the code it seems like a small change if one knows how to set the ResourceManager, but from the comments it seems like a hard job. I don't understand why. For MinLenghtAttribute we have

```
public class MinLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
public MinLengthAttribute(int length)
        : base(SR.MinLengthAttribute_ValidationError)
    {
        Length = length;
    }
    // The rest of the code
 }
```

The SR is as below :

```
namespace System
{
    internal static partial class SR
    {
   internal static string MinLengthAttribute_ValidationError => 
    GetResourceString("MinLengthAttribute_ValidationError");
    // The rest of the code
    }
 }
```

One should be able to chance the value in GetResourceString and achieve my goal. Right?

Comment: Looks like this article will give you what you need (https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/combining-asp-net-core-attributes-with-value-objects/)

Comment: surely you should only be changing the error message in the case that you have a specific piece ov information to provide? such as "A name of at least 10 characters in length is required to create a user.". The others being left as the default would make it easier to find cases where you've not provided a specific error message and indicate a place for improvement.

Comment: @RyanWilson Not really. He has just implemented his own ValidationAttributes. I prefer to use the built-in attributes if possible

Comment: @TheHitchenator That is exactly my point. But I don't want to use the default error message from dotnet. The requirement of my project is to return a specific general error message for each of the cases.

Comment: @RyanWilson Why would I need to do that? It is just a text that the validation is returning and it is reading it from the resource manager. If I know how I can change the values in ResourceManager in dotnet core I will achieve my goal. Is it such a big deal to do?

Comment: @AshkanSirous This article uses implementation of `IValidationMetadataProvider` along with a custom resource file -> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788092/how-to-provide-localized-validation-messages-for-validation-attributes) then adds to services in the startup. Perhaps this will be more to your liking. Answer by `jlchavez`